# Transform class or interface properties types recursively

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics, mapped-types

Is possible to transform Class/Interface properties into certain types?
My goal is to transform all primitive properties into boolean and array-like properties into element-like types where also properties are transformed like in the parent object.

Example:

```js
interface Skill {
  name: string;
  level: 'beginner' | 'intermediate' | 'advanced';
}

interface User {
  id: number;
  email: string;
  skills: Skill[];
}

/**
 * TO
 */

interface QueriedSkill {
  name: boolean;
  level: boolean;
}

interface QueriedUser {
  id: boolean;
  email: boolean;
  skills: QueriedSkill;
}
```

The goal is to create such an interface dynamically:

```js
type QueriedUser = TransformToQueried<User>
```

Want to use this for my graphql server for optimized data resolution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's gonna look something like this:

```
type Queried<T> = T extends object ? {
    [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends ReadonlyArray<unknown> ? Queried<T[K][number]> : T[K] extends object ? Queried<T> : boolean;
} : boolean;
```

It's a recursive type that turns all non-objects into type `boolean`. In the case of arrays, it unwraps it into its elements and operates on that instead.

I don't think it needs to work with tuples but if it does, you can comment on here for an edit.

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/mpLMzm)

Comment: This is cool thanks for your effort.  There is slightly deviation from expected result and that is that this results in 
```typescript
interface QueriedUser {
  id: boolean;
  email: boolean;
  skills: QueriedSkill[];
}
```

and not

```typescript
interface QueriedUser {
  id: boolean;
  email: boolean;
  skills: QueriedSkill;
}
```
Do you think we can improve also this one?

Comment: Ah I did not see that the result isn't an array. Of course we can fix that. Edited now.

Comment: Huge kudos thank your and respect to your TS skills.

Comment: I am extremely grateful for your help and effort, unfortunately, can not make it work with circular dependencies (which is the sad case of the project I work on :()
I do not expect you to improve also that (I doubt that is doable) but if you are having fun pushing the limits of TS here is an example:

`interface Skill {
  name: string;
  user: User;
}

interface User {
  id: number;
  email: string;
  skills: Skill[];
}`

Comment: @JurajZovinec You can always ask a follow-up question on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

After some time I returned back to this topic and with help of @caTS came up with a solution tolerating also circular dependencies:

```js
type Queried<T> = T extends object
  ? Partial<{
      [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends ReadonlyArray<unknown>
        ? Queried<T[K][number]> | false
        : T[K] extends object
        ? Queried<T[K]> | false
        : boolean;
    }>
  : boolean;
```